# Constructing Dataflow pipeline with same transforms on side outputs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are building a streaming pipeline where the data may encounter different errors at several steps, such as serialization error, validation error, and runtime error on writing to the storage. Whenever the error happens, we direct the data to a side output. The error handling logic is the same on these side outputs. We write the data to a common error storage for post processing / reporting.

There are at least three options to construct the pipleine. (pseudo code below)

1. Handle each side output with a new instance of the transform.

   ```
   sideOutput1.apply(new HandleErrorTransform());
   sideOutput2.apply(new HandleErrorTransform());
   ```
2. Handle each side output with a single instance of the transform.

   ```
   Transform errorTransform = new HandleErrorTransform();
   sideOutput1.apply(errorTransform);
   sideOutput2.apply(errorTransofrm);
   ```
3. Flatten the output from these side outputs and use a single transform to handle all the errors.

   ```
   PCollectionList.of(sideOutput1).and(sideOutput2)
     .apply(Flatten.<ErrorMessage>pCollections())
     .apply(new HandleErrorTransform());
   ```

Is there any advice on which one to use, for better scalability and performance? Or maybe it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 2 are basically the same -- since the pipeline is serialized the sharing doesn't offer any advantages.

Option 3 may have have some advantages since it is easier for you to add more logic to that path. It will likely be a bit easier to scale since there will only be one source writing elements to the final location, and that means fewer buffers, more opportunities to batch elements, etc.

One downside of 3 is that the use of flatten will hold up any windows created in the `HandleErrorTransform` until all of the main pipeline has processed those timestamps. This may be desirable -- all errors from records in this window -- but if not can be addressed using triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Ben. We are not creating any windows in the transform for error handling. But the error messages may have been emitted from the steps with different windows. Some earlier steps are in the global window scope, while the latter steps are behind a GroupByKey on a window based on processing time. Curious about what the effect will be when merging inputs with different windows. But that may deserve its own topic.

Comment: I believe `Flatten` will require that all the inputs have the same windowing. In this case you may need to do a variant of 3 applying global windows to each `sideOutput` before the flatten. If the `HandleErrorTransform` includes a `GroupByKey` or other aggregation you may also need to insert a trigger that fires periodically, since the `GlobalWindow` will otherwise never emit data.